# Pointing domain to my own static IP address at home

Tags: dns, domain

I just bought a domain name and set up my site.

The problem is the hosting company does not support Apache, and some of the features of PHP are not available on the server.

I have a static IP address at home and I want to use Apache, so I want to host my site at home. What should I do to set the domain to point to my own static IP address so that all my files are on my own server at home?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/90721/run-web-site-from-home

Answer (score 0):

- Access DNS Zone and change it according your own IP address ( at least your %servername.tld / www.%servername%.tld records )
- Change Modem/Router config so it forwards packets to your apache

---

Any other need would be 'based' on your actual network configuration, which is unknown.
In a 'basic' envirorment ( Modem/Router natting the hosts ) this should be enough.

---

NA: i'm assuming local apache server is allready configured and you can somehow change DNS record/IP association.

Comment: What is that final remark supposed to mean? Please edit your answer to provide the info instead of a hint.